# find and replace with regex in output

Tags: regex, sed, latex

I got a huge LaTeX file with bad references to figures, for example it says

```
"... So in the figure 3-12 we see ... similar to figure 3-1..."
```

where it should be

```
"... So in the figure \ref{fig:3-12} we see ... similar to figure \ref{fig:3-1}..."
```

For save time, silly me, I tought a find/replace like:

**find:** `figure 3-`
**replace:** `figure \ref{fig:3-`

Which returned:

```
"... So in the figure \ref{fig:3-12 we see ... similar to figure \ref{fig:3-1..."
```

now the closing brackets

```
sed 's#/ref{fig:3-\d+#\ref{fig:3-\d+}#g' main.tex
```

which yields

```
"... So in the figure \ref{fig:3-\d+} we see ... similar to figure \ref{fig:3-\d+}..."
```

What is wrong friends?. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture any streaks of digits and hyphens after the word `figure`:

```
s="... So in the figure 3-12 we see ... similar to figure 3-1..."
echo $s | sed -E 's#(figure +)([0-9-]+)#\1\\ref{fig:\2}#g'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/1EjNRa).

Example on how to do the inplace replacement with a *.bak copy (tested in Ubuntu):

```
sed -i.bak -E 's#(figure +)([0-9-]+)#\1\\ref{fig:\2}#g' main.tex
```

**Details**

- `(figure +)` - Group 1: captures the `figure` substring and 1 or more spaces (replace with `[[:blank:]]+` to match any spaces or tabs)
- `([0-9-]+)` - Group 2: one or more digits or `-`.

The replacement is:

- `\1` - a replacement backreference to Group 1 value
- `\\ref{fig:` - a literal `\ref{fig:` substring (the backslash must be escaped as it is a "special" char)
- `\2` - a replacement backreference to Group 2 value
- `}` - a `}` char.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed`:

```
s="... So in the figure 3-12 we see ... similar to figure 3-1..."
sed -E 's/[0-9]+-[0-9]+/\\ref{fig:&}/g' <<< "$s"

... So in the figure \ref{fig:3-12} we see ... similar to figure \ref{fig:3-1}...
```

So we are matching a pattern `[0-9]+-[0-9]+` to match `number-number` pattern. In the replacement `&` is back-reference of fully matched string by regex pattern.

Comment: You're matching every `\d+-\d+` in the text. Make `figure` part of your pattern.